# Enzyme simulate not changing textarea

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Im tryng a simple test to verify if the user can enter text on a text area, but for some reason the simulate method doesnt work..

CommentBox component

```
class CommentBox extends Component {
  state = { comment: "" };
  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ comment: event.value });
  };
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ comment: "" });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <h4>
          Add a CommentBox
          <textarea  onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.comment} />
          <div>
            <button onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>Submit Comment</button>
          </div>
        </h4>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

The test
export default CommentBox;

```
let wrapped;
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapped = mount(<CommentBox />);

});
afterEach(() => {
    wrapped.unmount();
});


it('has a text area and a button', () => {

    expect(wrapped.find('textarea').length).toEqual(1);
    expect(wrapped.find('button').length).toEqual(1);
});

it('has a text area that users can type in' ,() => {
    const textarea = wrapped.find('textarea');
    textarea.simulate('change', {
      target: {  , 
        value: 'testing' }
    });
    wrapped.update();
    expect(textarea.prop('value')).toEqual('testing');
});
```

error :

● has a text area that users can type in

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Expected: "testing"
Received: ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue #1

```
handleChange = event => {
  this.setState({ comment: event.value });
};
```

Actually value is `event.target.value`. But I believe better make destructuring right in arguments:

```
handleChange = ({ target: { value }}) => {
  this.setState({ comment: value });
};
```

Issue#2:
after rerendering you have to run `.find('textarea')` again instead of relying on previous value; also you don't ever need `wrapped.update()`

So

```
it('has a text area that users can type in' ,() => {
    wrapped.find('textarea').simulate('change', {
      target: { value: 'testing' }
    });
    expect(wrapped.find('textarea').props().value).toEqual('testing');
});
```

works fine.